# Beveling along a straight path — why does size change?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I'm trying to sweep a profile curve along a path curve, where the path curve (the one to which I'll apply the bevel) is a simple set of straight lines and right angles.

When I set the path curve's Bevel Object to the profile curve, I get roughly the desired result, except that the size of the profile curve gets bigger as it approaches the ends of the path. Why is that, and what do I do about it? (I tried setting a straight taper curve, but that doesn't help.)

Here's a simple blend file showing the problem:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Usually if I am working with a Curve, I am able to select a control point and use Alt-S to Shrink/Fatten the curve at that point. Yours seems to be locked somehow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add images of the issue.  Do not make the question dependent on people downloading your file only. And in the future use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/to make a permanent link to the file. If the link to your file disappears from the current host then your question will not be useful for other users who are facing a similar problem/

Comment: the profile doesn't get "*bigger as it approaches the ends*" it actually gets narrower in tight corners. It's a limitation of the current bevel system, see the comment above for more details.

Comment: See what happens when you turn on 2D in the Curve.

Comment: @ Craig D Jones ... yeah I was wondering why his curve couldn't do the Alt-S modification on the ends but I made a copy of the original curve and then it worked! Strange.

Comment: @cegaton Edited as requested. Thanks all for the quick responses.

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!